Relay controlling DC motor welding shut
I am controlling a fairly large DC motor using a relay. The motor draws approximately 7A at 36V. I am controlling it with a relay rated at 110VDC, 50A. To protect against back-EMF, I placed a transient voltage suppressor across the motor to clamp the voltage down. Using an oscilloscope, I verified repeatedly that back-EMF spikes do not exceed 68V.
However, occasionally, the relay contacts still get stuck shut. After some time, they get "unstuck", I'm guessing due to contraction once they cool down being enough to break the weld.
How can I avoid this happening? I don't think I'm exceeding the specifications of the relay. Do I need a proper snubber? Am I misunderstanding something about relay tolerances?
Thanks for any advice.

What is the hp rating of the relay?

How confident are you that you are driving the coil of the relay hard enough?  I've seen weak drive cause this, presumably because the contacts a fluttering more.

The HP rating of the relay is 1200W. I'm driving the relay coil at exactly the 24V that the datasheet recommends, using a resistor to drop from the 36V supply rail. I'll link the relay datasheet: https://www.citrelay.com/Catalog%20Pages/RelayCatalog/J115F%2050amp.pdf

A single series resistor?  What value?
